# Unable to display div tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display `douter` (my outer div) in the external JavaScript file but when I click on the button in my HTML page it does not show.i want to replace the div display with the outer div The only error that I see is this:

> [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 15ms]

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="display">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Play Quiz" onclick="generator()"/>
</div>
```

... and here's my JavaScript:

```
function generator() {   
    button.style.display = "none";

    var douter = document.createElement("div");        
    douter.setAttribute("class", "douter");     
    douter.id = "douter";

    var dinner = document.createElement("div");   
    dinner.setAttribute("class", "dinner");     
    dinner.id = "dinner"; 

    var btn = document.createElement("button");      
    btn.innerHTML = "Next";
    // document.getElementById("display").style.display = "none";

    var rad = document.createElement("input");    
    rad.setAttribute("type", "radio");    
    rad.setAttribute("name", "rad");    
    rad.setAttribute("id", "rad");    
    rad.setAttribute("value", "rad");
    // document.write(Questions.question.length);

    douter.appendChild(dinner);    
    dinner.appendChild(rad);    
    dinner.appendChild(btn);    
}
```

I want to hide the display div and replace it with the outer div and its contents.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I've fixed up the formatting in your post for you, but for future reference you can format your code by selecting your code then clicking the `{}` button, or indenting your code using 4 spaces. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [http/1.1 status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)?

Comment: where you appending your douter div finally?

Answer (score 1):

```
dinner.appendChild(btn);
document.body.appendChild(douter);
}
```

I think you missed to append created elements to body

Comment: what should be done if the display div has to be replaced with outer div

Comment: document.getElementById("display").remove(); you can remove old by this way.

Comment: want to replace that with the outer div, tried yours but same output

Answer (score 0):

You append the children but never actually append `douter` to the document.

Add this code at the end of your function...

***If you want to simply add the new div:***

```
document.appendChild(douter);
```

***If you want it to replace the display div:***

This assumes that displayDiv is at root (not inside another div)

```
var displayDiv = document.getElementById('display');
document.replaceChild(displayDiv, douter);
```

Now, if your display div is inside another div, then you need to get a reference to whatever div contains displayDiv. Since you didn't post more of your HTML structure, I'll post a quick example. Obviously you will need to make it work with your code.

Let's suppose this is your structure:

```
<div id="someComtainer">
    <div id="display"> <!-- ... Content ... --> </div>
</div>
```

Then you need a reference to the div with id "someContainer" to replace the display div:

```
var someContainer = document.getElementById('someContainer');
var displayDiv = document.getElementById('display');
someContainer.replaceChild(displayDiv, douter);
```

If you post your actual HTML I can make this more specific, but really this should give you enough to get your desired result.

***Alternately, use style.display to show/hide two divs:***

HTML:

```
<div id="message" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="display"> <!-- ... Content ... --> </div>
```

JS:

```
var messageDiv = document.getElementById('message');
var displayDiv = document.getElementById('display');

messageDiv.appendChild(displayDiv, douter);

messageDiv.style.display = "block";
displayDiv.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: i want to hide the display div and only show the outer div and its contents @davidkhaykin

Comment: @user3342712: That is a good thing to post in your question for future reference. See my updated answer.

Comment: yeah i was looking out for this but it disappears and following error message is shown in the console TypeError: document.replaceChild.appendChild is not a function

Comment: @user3342712: That was a typo which I since fixed in my answer...it's just `document.replaceChild(oldChild, newChild);`

Comment: actually i need only a single div which should be replaced by another div i tried your code but it gives node not found

Comment: @user3342712: it says that because (most likely) your display div is inside some other div / element, right? You need to get a reference to whatever element contains the display div, and then do someElement.replaceChild() ... If you're not sure, post a bit more of your HTML so we can see the element that contains your display div.